# "The stub received bad data" exception in Windows RPC call

Tags: c++, windows, rpc, idl

We are facing the following issue:
The architecture is as follows:
A c++ native client application is connected to a native c++ server application via pipe RPC based on a IDL file.
I'm not particular savvy in this domain and havent coded the relevant parts but it works since a long time.

Since some days, one of our client-server tests fails.
Examining the issue shows that there is an exception in the very low-level RPC communication part:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF2649A388 (KernelBase.dll) in application.exe: 0x000006F7: The stub received bad data. occurred
```

The stack contains calls to functions in *rpcrt4.dll*.

Now the thing is we don't have any recent modifications in these parts of the code.
Neither in the functions on the client involved in that particular server RPC call.
Also, the same error occurs on my dev machine also with an older version of the code (for which the tests passed fine when this older version was tested on the test machines).
So i suspect some external issue, like updates to the windows libraries or such.

Did anyone encounter this error out of a sudden?

How should i go forward to debug and pinpoint the issue?
What i have done so far:
Debugged the client and server, and i see the call coming in on the server and the function executes fine.
It is when the result is being sent back to the client when the exception is fired on the client.

This is on Windows 10 x64, developed with Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: It is a basic DLL Hell problem, a version mismatch between the server and client.  Could be the library DLL, that would be somewhat obvious.  But this error is generated from the proxy/stub or the type library content, the more obscure parts of this kind of interop.